# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router> even though my structure is good

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm getting this error :

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>
```

But what's driving me crazy is the fact that My "Switch" tag actually is surrounded by "BrowserRouter"..

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Switch} from "react-router";
....
function App() {
    return (
        <AuthContext>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="app">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                        <Route exact path='/register' component={Register}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AuthContext>
    );
}
```

When checking the router modules versions, I get this :

```
├─┬ connected-react-router@6.9.2 extraneous
│ └── react-router@6.0.2 deduped invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.0.2 extraneous
│ └── react-router@6.0.2 deduped invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router
└── react-router@6.0.2 invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router extraneous
```

Comment: Check versions for react-router and react-router-dom packages, are they the same?

Comment: @skyboyer I need more details behind your answer, what do I need to check exactly ?

Comment: Why aren't you importing `Switch` from `react-router-dom`? Skyboyer is asking you to run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from your project directory and report back the versions you have installed. Do you have any other `Switch` components rendered outside this `App` component?

Comment: @DrewReese, I have this issue "Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'." when importing Switch from react-router-dom

Comment: You've probably installed `react-rotuer-dom` version 6, which doesn't export a `Switch` component as it was replaced by the `Routes` component. The version ca be verified if you run the `npm list` command specified in earlier comment.

Comment: you use it like react router v5, but you installed react router v6. v6 docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation. or install v5

Comment: From what I can see I don't think `connected-react-router` has been updated yet to be compatible with RRDv6. If you run `npm un -s react-router-dom` then `npm i -s react-router-dom@5.3.0` to downgrade back to DDRv5 do you still see the issue with the `Switch` and router?

Comment: @DrewReese, you can post an answer i guess since downgrading react-router-dom version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it does not appear `connected-react-router` supports `react-router-dom` version 6.

> ```
> ├─┬ connected-react-router@6.9.2 extraneous
> │ └── react-router@6.0.2 deduped invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router
> ├─┬ react-router-dom@6.0.2 extraneous
> │ └── react-router@6.0.2 deduped invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router
> └── react-router@6.0.2 invalid: "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0" from node_modules/connected-react-router extraneous
> ```

You are on the latest version of `connected-react-router` (6.9.2) and you can see [here](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/package.json#L34-L40) it still lists `react-router-dom` v4/5 as a peer dependency.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "history": "^4.7.2",
  "react": "^16.4.0 || ^17.0.0",
  "react-redux": "^6.0.0 || ^7.1.0",
  "react-router": "^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0", // <-- not v6
  "redux": "^3.6.0 || ^4.0.0"
},
```

Though it seems there is possibly a plan to update `connected-react-router` to support `react-router-dom` version 6. There's some discussion [here](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/543) in `connected-react-router`'s issue tracker with a possible work-around.

Outside of this possible work around if you've no pressing need, or desire, to use `react-router-dom` version 6 then I suggest reverting back to version 5. From your project's directory run the following commands to uninstall v6 and install v5.

- `npm uninstall -s react-router-dom`
- `npm install -s react-router-dom@5.3.0` *or any other specific v5.x version*